# How set dynamic size for input queue on Solaris?

Tags: c, unix, terminal, solaris

I read from terminal by fgets with size of buffer 80 bytes. But when I write very long line in terminal (more than MAX_INPUT constant from limits.h) then terminal rings me BEL sound (IMAXBEL is enable). How I can input such very long lines in terminal? I can't force users input special symbols. I can only rewrite program.

I tried use #undef MAX_INPUT - this don't work.
If I disable IMAXBEL then terminal just clears input queue after MAX_INPUT byte from input and next byte of input save in start of queue... and does this until user end of input.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you pipe your long input using a file:

```
./myprog < input_file
```

It might be related to the terminal implementation. In such a case, using input from file is a better choice (although a better choice could be to re-implement the input logic to allow multi-line input)

Comment: Input logic to allow multi-line input, but need allow very long line too. I can't limit user only input from file because of target requirements not allow it.

Comment: Then the most portable solution is using files to avoid any tty limitations